# Inability to use Road Grapher plugin in Q Gis 2.18.2

Tags: qgis

I am a QGis 2.18.2 user who is unable to use road grapher plugin as the system says it is not configured. However, I can see the plugin in the side panel.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Have you tried updating your QGIS? What did googling yield? has the plugin worked earlier?

Comment: No, I haven't used this plugin earlier. You mean I should download the higher version of QGIS?

Comment: At least 2.18.27, since many plugins don't work with 3.x.

Comment: Oh alright ! I will try that!